# Unable to mount /tmp to /mnt/tmp properly

Tags: mount, partitioning, tmp, umount

I have a EC2 instance, and I have a very small `/tmp` size which I want to increase. So I tried to mount `/tmp` to `/mnt/tmp` using:

```
sudo mount -B /tmp/ /mnt/tmp/
```

This did mount it to `/mnt/tmp`. But when I create a file in `/tmp`, the device `/dev/xvda1` gets filled and NOT `/dev/xvdf`.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      15341728 11154228   3458992  77% /
/dev/xvdf      103081248 15452284  82369700  16% /mnt
```

What I want to achieve is that `/tmp` should use the space in `/mnt` and not in the root partition.

Comment: Remove /rmp and symlink it?

Comment: @Rinzwind No didn't work that. When I try `mktemp` it throws: `‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory`.

Comment: sorry but why mktemp? For instance: this works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5489/how-to-safely-move-tmp-to-a-different-volume   and I mean the setup used in the question (but -do- use the `-a`).